# Elasticsearch NEST: ordering terms aggregation with multiple criteria

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Using NEST, I need to be able to order a terms aggregation with multiple criteria (requires ElasticSearch 1.5 or later).  For example:

`"order": [{"avg_rank": "desc"}, {"avg_score": "desc"}]`

This is working great using the raw JSON that I created to verify I was getting the expected behavior.  Now, in trying to translate that over to code using the NEST library, I'm not seeing how that would be accomplished.

The `OrderDescending()` method has only one implementation that takes a string for the key.  I need a C# "params" type method that can take a list of `OrderDescending()` and\or `OrderAscending()` elements.

1. Is there a way to do this in NEST that I'm overlooking?
2. Is there a way in NEST to work around this where I can inject a little raw JSON where I need it?

FWIW, I've been using the "fluent" style to create my queries.

**EDIT:**
I see that, using "object initializer" syntax, I could manually create the dictionary and add my criteria elements.  Problem is, I have large amounts of code written in "fluent" syntax.  So,

3. Is there a way to use an "object initializer" object and convert it to a "fluent" descriptor?  In this case, a TermsAggregator to a TermsAggregationDescriptor?

**EDIT 2:**
I should have mentioned originally that I tried `.OrderDescending("avg_rank").OrderDescending("avg_score")` already.  That simply took that last one in the chain.  In looking at the code, I can see why.  Each call to `OrderDescending` blindly news up the dictionary instead of checking to see if one was already newed up and adding a new key to the dictionary if it already exists.

Based on this, I believe this is a bug for which I have entered a report here:
[OrderDescending and OrderAscending cannot be chained for multi-criteria ordering](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1396)

**EDIT 3:**
I appreciate all the answers (some of which are getting deleted) because they're helping drive this along and are responsible for these edits.  I should also have mentioned originally that I discovered that:

`"order": { "avg_rank": "desc", "avg_score": "desc" }`

does not work.  I don't know why for sure but ES will only use the last one in that case.  It has be a list of dictionaries as shown in my example above at the top.  I've verified that correctly sub-orders the aggregation on the second element.  So, the underlying object cannot be typed as a simple dictionary.  I've also added this information to the bug report I created (as noted in **EDIT 2**).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Martijn Laarman of the NEST team was very responsive and kind enough to provide a work around for the bug I reported in ***EDIT 2*** of the description above.  The fix can be found in the comments of that same bug report: [Work around for NEST library multi-criteria aggregation ordering](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1396).

Note that he provided a work around for both object initializer and fluent syntaxes (the one I needed).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the fluent syntax you can just chain the sorts together.

Sample:

```
    var esClient = ninjectKernel.Get<IElasticClient>();
    var query = esClient.Search<RedemptionES>(s=> s
        .SortAscending(a=>a.Date)
        .SortDescending(d=>d.Input.User.Name)
        );
```

Response:

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "input.user.name": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm ordering a terms aggregation, not sorting search results.  At any rate, see "Edit 2" above WRT chaining.